# insert img inside href in php

Tags: php, image, href, put

how to replace **img** inside **href** on this php code

this is the **img** code

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/<?php echo $term->name;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $term->name;?>">
```

i wanna replace it inside **href** in this code

```
<?php
echo '<a href="?cat='.$term->term_id.'">
    <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>';
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php echo '<a href="?cat='.$term->term_id.'"> <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/<?php echo $term->name;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $term->name;?>"> </a>'; echo "</div>"; } ?>
```

Comment: It's code. Therefore it's text. You can place it anywhere you want, as long as it ends up being valid php+html.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise, I can't figure out what the question is exactly, and please format your code a bit before posting. But yeah pretty much what @MarcB said.

Comment: I can't, when i try it, it shows me and error in my website


`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected`

Comment: Maybe you tried to keep `<?php` when you moved it into the `echo`? When you're using `echo` you should concatenate strings, not switch in and out of PHP execution mode.

Comment: I'm also not sure what your question means. `href` has to contain a URL to link to, you can't put an image there.

Comment: Do you mean you want the image inside the `<a>...</a>`?

Comment: yes @Barmar

i try this 
`
 <?php
                                echo '<a href="?cat='.$term->term_id.'">

                                 <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                           <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/<?php echo $term->name;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $term->name;?>">

                                      </a>';
                                echo "</div>";
                              }
                         ?>
                       `

Comment: You see, you're doing exactly what I said you shouldn't do. You can't have `<?php` inside `echo`.

Comment: so what should i do @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix `<?php` into `echo` -- that's used for getting back into PHP execution mode when you're outputting raw text, but you're already in PHP execution.

Since `bloginfo()` echoes its output instead of returning a string, you need to split this up into multiple statements.

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="?cat='.$term->term_id.'"> <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <img class="img-responsive" src="';
bloginfo('template_url');
echo '/images/'.$term->name.'.png" alt="'.$term->name.'"> </a>'; 
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: I was missing a `"`, try it now.

Comment: same problem: `arse error: syntax error, unexpected`

Comment: I just tried it, I don't get a syntax error. The problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: yes worked @Barmar, problem in my code but it show this text `/images/` in bottom of every image

Comment: Sorry, I didn't edit out the ?>` correctly from your code. Try now.